# Magmi product deleter does not delete attributes?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, attributes, magmi, delete

I use Magmi Product deleter for deleting products from Magento 1.8.

The plugin has a function removeFromFlat() to delete all records of the product from the catalog_product_flat_% tables.

What is the reason this is not done for all catalog_product_entity_% tables as well?

When I remove a product now, all attribute-values remain in the database.

Comment: Have you checked that they are staying? Maybe those are handled by sql foreign keys and on delete cascading?

Answer (score 1):

For the eav system there should be foreign keys on all the tables like `catalog_product_entity_datetime` so that if the main product is deleted then mysql will also delete all the appropriate items from all the other tables.